# Pushing and pulling JSON data with a filter from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

I am working on a REACT JS project in an attempt to create a small Todo List app.

I have my data in a JSON file, currently hosted on jsonbin.io, in a format that looks like this...

```
{
  "moduleAccess": {
    "tasks": [
      {
        "email": "campbell@yahoo.com",
        "id": 0,
        "task_name": "Call mom",
        "due_date": 44875,
        "completed": true
      },
      {
        "email": "palsner593@gmail.com",
        "id": 1,
        "task_name": "Buy eggs",
        "due_date": 44880,
        "completed": false
      },
      {
        "email": "rob@gmail.com",
        "id": 2,
        "task_name": "Go to dog park",
        "due_date": 44879,
        "completed": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Currently, I fetch the data using jsonbin.io's API. The data is brought into a variable called *Tasks*. If a user updates a specific to-do item, deletes a to-do item, or creates a new one, all those changes are put back into the *Tasks* variable. I can then send push those tasks to the server.

What I explained above works fine; however, the caveat is that I would like to allow multiple users to log in and then pull only the Todo items that pertain to their respective email.

Say, **campbell@yahoo.com** is logged in to my app. In this case, in my fetch pull request, I can specify that I would only like records with **campbell@yahoo.com**

```
 async function loadData() {
    const newPath = '$..tasks[?(@.email==' + campbell@yahoo.com + ')]';
    console.log(newPath);
    const url = 'https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/*binid*?meta=false'
    const response = await
      fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "X-Master-Key": key,
          "X-JSON-Path": newPath
        }
      });
    const data = await response.json();
    setTasks([...data]);  //or whatever
    console.log(tasks);
  }
```

This concept works as well. However, when pushing my task data back to a server after a user has made changes, I encounter an issue. The API I am using does not seem to allow parameters for specifying the JSON path upon PUSH. JSON-PATH is only allowed for a pull request. So when I push data to the server, it seems as if all JSON data will be overwritten, regardless of the user.

Does anybody have an alternative way to push/pull user-specific data? I am sorry if the detail I have provided is unnecessary. Not sure what the easiest way to approach this problem is for a react app.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I did a little research in jsonbin.io API and came up with a solution that might work.

So I'm not really sure that this will work, but still.

When creating a new bin, you can add it to some collection using `X-Collection-Id`. So you might be able to make next flow:

1. When user register, create a separate bin for tasks for this user
2. Add user with bin id to some users collection where you will have all your users
3. When user auth, get his bin id using filters that you used in your code and store it for future use somewhere in your app.
4. After this you will be able to fetch users tasks by that bin id and modify it, cause now it will be a separate bin for each user and you can simply override all of its content.

Hope this works.